# retrieve json array as array without quotes in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I am using json datatype in mysql to store array of numbers as ["9","10"] in a table

Then I do

```
select numbers from table  WHERE id = 1
```

This return 'numbers' as ["9","10"] in console but when I try to access the array in the code it is shown as "[\"9\",\"10\"]"

I tried JSON_UNQUOTE but it returns "[\"9\",\"10\"]" the same result.

How do I get it as an array as ["9","10"] and not "[\"9\",\"10\"]"

Comment: Can you try with json_decode($result);?

Comment: yes that works but if it is json data field, we need not decode it in our script right ..?  m i making any mistake

Comment: i think you need to change datatype